# Returning a value from function?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a function to analyze some text and a regular expression pattern. Example:

```
import re
def foo(input_pattern, text):
    pattern = re.compile(r'input_patern', re.I)
    find = pattern.findall(text)
    ans = ' '.join(i for i in find).lower()
    '''some how return'''
text = input('Test: ')
'''Text could be: My name is Joe Joe Joe '''
input_pattern = input('Pattern: ')
'''Pattern could be: '(Name|Joe)' '''
foo(input_pattern, text)
'''Get ans'''
print(ans)
```

However, I can't seem to get a string (ans) form the function. I did look around for a answer, but could not find a working example. If you feel up to it, could you tell me how I would use concatenation to make a expression that depends on a string. I am using python 3.6.4 and am using Mac OS X.

Comment: You should read through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). The part about defining functions is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).  You should also know that comments in python are lines that start with `#`.

Comment: It says it is not properly formatted if I use #. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Return a sensible value from the function and assign the result of the function call to a variable. Note that the `ans` variable inside your function is local and, therefore, not accessible outside of the function:

```
def foo(input_pattern, text):
    # ... 
    return ' '.join(i for i in find).lower()  # return!

# ...
ans = foo(input_pattern, text)  # assign!
print(ans)
```

Comment: How would I do this but make the pattern a string? I have tried string concatenation but I get this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findall'. **THIS IS ONLY WHEN I TRY AND USE STRING CONCATENATION.** Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need to add keyword `return` to the end of your function `foo`, and add the value or variable you want to return. I've modified your code to illustrate the example:

```
import re
def foo(input_pattern, text):
    pattern = re.compile(r'input_patern', re.I)
    find = pattern.findall(text)
    ans = ' '.join(i for i in find).lower()
    return ans
text = input('Test: ')
'''Text could be: My name is Joe Joe Joe '''
input_pattern = input('Pattern: ')
'''Pattern could be: '(Name|Joe)' '''
ans = foo(input_pattern, text)
'''Get ans'''
print(ans)
```

Keep in mind, that you can return multiple values, if needed, just separate them with `,`

Comment: Also, just to avoid misunderstanding, I want to note that you don't have to name variable to store return value with the same name, you used within the function.

Comment: It just brings back ''.

Comment: try to print 'ans' within function. Maybe this is the correct returning value?